# Mutiny to save the boss' job

Tags: employer-relations, employees

This is a somewhat unique situation I'm sure.

I work for a small business with 16 employees total. Our boss/owner, who is also the company's controller and accountant, took on 3 "silent" partners several years ago with equal shares all around, two of them happen to husband and wife. They have been actively working on squeezing him out for a couple years now and were recently able to get the third vote needed to fire him.

They have hired a replacement who is admittedly unqualified to take over all of the responsibilities being left open after his last day, the new hire wasn't fully informed of what his role in the dealership would entail before he was hired.

The boss has tried everything in his power to keep his role there, and we employees fear that the business will fail in his absence and all agree there's no reason for him to be removed in the first place aside from the greed of his partners (I'm not going into details but we've been informed of one of these partners' past accusations of illegal business practices).

Today I told him I am going to get everyone on the same page and draft a letter from the collective employees his partners tactfully and professionally informing them of our decision against him being fired.  Not a request, not a suggestion, a black and white notification. I won't be making any threats, most of us are ready to walk out as it is and they're well aware of it at this point.

I told the man I'm going to save his job, am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Kudos on actually wanting to keep your manager around. But you can't make a "decision against him being fired" because you didn't hire him and you're not a partner. What is your letter going to say, more specifically?

Comment: In a nutshell, that we as a group all agree he needs to stay where he's at

Comment: I said I won't be making any threats because the fact that most of us are ready to walk has already been relayed to them by their new hire via the numerous ass chewings he's already received in his first week there.  I don't need to make a threat, it's already on the table.

Comment: @BTM your situation is not that unique. What you say and what you do are two different things. If you disagree, instead of saying things which is akin to brassing hot air, do what you said: **Resign** and build something else with your boss.
In the same thing, if you are asking question here, it means that you are scared... Don't be a hero if you cannot sustain the heat

Answer (score 9):

The new owners are just that - owners. Aside from being their workforce, you have no voice in *how* they run the company. Their company, their rules.

You say that you and your colleagues have reached a unanimous decision that you're "against" your boss being fired and you're going to "notify" ownership of this. What do you really think this will accomplish? A "notification" without action behind it, when you hold no stake in the decisions about how the company is run, is worthless. You may as well use the toddler's trick of holding your breath until they change their mind.

If you're ready to walk if your boss is fired, just do it. Otherwise your "notification" is pointless - there are no repercussions for the owners. Just empty threats.

Comment: It sounds to me like the OP is suggesting the entire work force go on strike until their demands are met.  There would definitely be repercussions for the owners.  Whether the strike would be successful or not is another question.

Comment: this sounds like a classic strike, and assuming that everyone is onboard with it, it will almost certainly be a serious threat to the company. The real question is is everyone onboard?  If it's just the OP that is willing to walk, then even if he is a key employee, the owners will probably consider him easily replacable.  As for repercussions to the owners -- what they expect the reprecussions to be and what they actually will be, no one can know until after the fact.  Firing the manager could result in the company being worth billions in 2 years or bankruptcy. I'd bet against the first.

Comment: I know for sure that half are ready to walk if they won't oblige.  All but two of the others have expressed desires to quit as well, i just haven't had a chance to get them in the loop yet.  This is an extremely loyal group of people, some have been a it 30 years. I'm still a new guy at 8 years.

Answer (score 9):

This is a power play amongst the bosses, you getting involved is very dangerous and I wouldn't advise it. Start searching for a new job would be a better option while you still have this one.

Roping everyone else in can get the whole lot of you sacked, and if it came to that you would probably find that it was just you as the ringleader who copped it, and the rest would back down so they can feed their families. Saying you're willing to walk out, and actually doing it are two very different things.

Comment: I agree completely with this. If I was one of the owners, I would go after the ring leader to make an example out of him. Then, I would go after the next ring leader that popped up. Are you sure everyone can hold the line? This can only work if everyone is united. And why can't your old boss find a new job? If he is that good, he should be able to find a new one.

Comment: Yep, no bosses/owners can afford to have terms dictated by their staff, make an example of someone, if the example doesn't work, sack as many as you need to until you have discipline. The one thing you do NOT do is cave in.